# Field level access to the particular user for the particular record

Tags: field-level-security, userrecordaccess, record-access-level

I have a scenario, Account "phone" field is only accessible to the system administrator and for normal user its locked. We have the requirement as if normal user want to change "phone" for the particular Account record he  will create a case. After verifying case System admin will give the access to the "phone" field of that Account record.

How can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way for to do this as i see it if you create two page layouts.

**1.** Page layout for normal user, without the phone field

**2.** Page layout for normal user, with the phone field

If the user wants to get that information as you mentioned, he creates a case. Then when the system admin approve the case, he can just switch from **page layout one**(without the phone field) to **page layout two**(with the phone field)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response..
This will work for all normal users, i want only to the user who has raise the case for "phone" field modification for particular Account record.

Comment: @sfbeginner this can work as same for 1 user or many users. Or you can try Amit suggestion, it looks decent.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than 'Case', you can utilize an approval process and/or. What you can do is -

1. Create one more phone field **"Original Ph Number"**
2. Write a w/f or before insert trigger or iniital approval action to copy number from Phone field to the new field that we created.
3. Next if the Admin approves this change let it be as it is, if he doesnt we can do it in approval rejection action to set the previous number from **"Original Ph Number"** to the Phone field.
4. **"Original Ph Number"** will not be present on page layout.

thanks,